# Google Scholar ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: google-scholar

I experience difficulties in login into my google scholar account. It always said ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and I can't access my account.

I have tried to access the Google Scholar website using Incognito mode, but still no good. I have also tried to clear all my cookies but still get the same error message.

How to solve this problem?

Thank you.

FYI: I am using Gsuite.

[image]

Comment: Please share more details. How is this related to programming?

Answer (score 1):

Activate your institution's Google Assistant in G Suite:

**Dashboard, Apps -> Additional Google Services -> Google Assistant**

Answer (score 0):

If this happens because you used a mail tied to an institution that changed its privacy policy regarding Google and disabled the access to the Google Assistant, there is still a solution: create a new google account, using a new primary email address on which you have the full privileges, but verify your google scholar email with your institution email. This will trigger a duplicate account verification and you will be able to choose what google scholar profile to keep.